# Disabling flashing on taskbar (windows10)

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop

Is there a way to prevent minimized windows from flashing on the Taskbar? It is marginally useful when it works fine but ordinary windows with absolutely nothing new to show flash all the time (at least on my machine).

The most egregious issue is when a random window from another virtual desktop, so I click it to get rid of the orange flash, and it whisks me away to a different virtual desktop. So I would also love to be able to disable this *specifically* in the context of virtual desktops. So I would like the option to be able to segregate these orange flashes to within their virtual desktops. Please help...

edit: this is the orange flash I'm talking about:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/bqoPcZE.png]

edit: being able to give this immense privilege's to disrupt me to specific hand picked application's would also be useful. when my email client flashes, that's useful, when notepad flashes that's not useful.

Comment: No flashing here on any machine 10 or 11.   Is this icon something that needs your attention?

Comment: @John I mean, I don't know what to say, win10 icons have been flashing since win10 existed. I edited in a picture of it.

Comment: Not on my or any customers machines (hundreds) I have seen except and only if attention is needed.

Comment: what do you mean by "attention is needed"? the APP thinks it needs my attention, I don't think so. I want them to be silent, as I deprive them of my attention on purpose.

Comment: I only see an icon flash if the app is busy doing something and needs an OK from me. That is the only time.

Comment: Yea, and I hate that soooo much. Especially when using virtual desktops, it takes me to different virtual desktops and disorients me. Or, in the picture example, Matlab is flashing. I havent the faintest clue why. I think I double clicked the app, opened up chrome, and the app loaded in the background as is telling me "okay boss Im all loaded up :)" But I dont care, Ill check when I need it.

Comment: There are two reasons a taskbar button (and window's title bar if visible) will flash. 1. The program says to do so. This is rare. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-flashwindowex. 2. The program has tried to set itself as the foreground window. If not allowed the title bar/ taskbar button will flash 3 times. In older versions of Windows focus would have been stolen. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow

Comment: @user1292580 "In older versions of Windows focus would have been stolen" that was a outrageous problem, glad it was fixed. But I want to be disrupted even less.

Comment: That was the compatibility trade off to prevent old (and new) programs from stealing focus. Flashing is the least worst option. See https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/100109-change-how-many-times-taskbar-button-flashes-windows-10-a.html for how to customise it.